# How do I validate maxLength on FormGroup / FormControl array elements in Angular?

Tags: angular

How would I go about adding a max length for strings inside of an array in a FormControl?

The following sets a validators on the number of elements, not the number of characters the elements inside the array can have:

```
 let formGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
     tags: new FormControl([], [Validators.maxLength(32)]),
```

});

Comment: I think you have to use a `FormArray` instead of a `FormControl`. https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#usage-notes

Comment: Please elaborate on the problem where and which length of which array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tom had mentioned, I needed to use FormArray and add FormControls to it.

Working Code:

```
 formGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
     tags: new FormArray([])}),

 //Function to add FormControls to FormArray
 addTag(tag: string) {
     this.formGroup
         .get('tags')
         .value.push(new FormControl(tag, Validators.maxLength(32)));
 }
```